# In Rev.5:6, is the "Lamb" one of the "four beasts in the midst of the throne" (KJV)?

Tags: revelation, kjv

> And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the throne and **of the four beasts**, and in the midst of the elders, stood a Lamb as it had been slain, having seven horns and seven eyes, which are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth.

It appears to me that the Lamb is of the four beasts (Lives). Why am I wrong?

Answer (score 8):

If that which is termed 'lamb' is one of the four beasts simply because it is in the midst of the four beasts, then that which is 'lamb' is also a part of the throne (as it is in the midst of the throne) and is also an elder (because it is in the midst of the elders).

This would lead to a blurring of what is revealed, rather than clarify what is revealed.

We are given imagery in order that we may envisage spiritualities. But that very aid is compromised if we blur the distinctions of separate, figurative images which are representative of distinct concepts.

Clearly, the Lamb is central and is pre-eminent and, clearly, all that *surround* the Lamb take their place and their status *from* the Lamb. But the Lamb is distinct from all around. Each of the items mentioned has a distinct form - the throne, the elders and the living creatures (these are ζῶον *zōon* - different from θηρῐ́ον *thēríon* which is the word used for the beast rising up out of the sea - Revelation 13:1 - and the beast coming up out of the earth - Revelation 13:11).

The position of the Son of man in the first section of the book and the Lamb, here, is surely reminiscent of the situation in the garden of Eden - the Tree of Life was in the midst. And we see that same Tree of Life mentioned elsewhere in Revelation - 2:7, 22:2, 22:14, 22:19.

The Lamb, as it had been slain, is surely the same One who was seen in the midst of the seven lampstands in the previous section of the book, judging the churches on earth. Now, here, he is also central to that which prevails in heaven. It is without doubt Jesus Christ, the Son of God, who has all pre-eminence and is central to the Gospel - throughout all four gospel accounts and throughout every epistle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.


In.3:3 Jesus replied to him, "Truly, I tell you emphatically, unless a person is born  from above 
 he cannot see the kingdom of God."

Gal.4:26 But the Jerusalem that is above is free, which is our mother.

Comment: ”By your reasoning, if that which is termed 'lamb' is one of the four beasts simply because it is in the midst of the four beasts,”—that is not his reasoning. If you appreciate the syntax, you will see ἐν μέσῳ precedes τοῦ θρόνου and τῶν πρεσβυτέρων but not τῶν τεσσάρων ζῴων. Since that is the basis of his question, a good answer will discuss *that* rather than a red herring.

Comment: @DerÜbermensch I fully appreciate your point and that, indeed, is a further valid question. But first, it is necessary to clarify concept. No, the lamb is distinct from the 'beasts' - in the same way as it is distinct from the elders (in whose midst it is). Your point, I repeat, is very valid - it is a further depth to consider. But that should be broached in a further question. And I have up-voted the question +1 to encourage that. –

Answer (score 3):

No, the Lamb is not of the four living creatures that surround the throne.  The conjunction "and" (kai) is linking the position of the four living creatures to the throne.  Look at it in Young's Literal Translation.

> *"and I saw, and lo, in the midst of the throne, and of the four living creatures, and in the midst of the elders, a Lamb hath stood as it had been slain,..."*  (Rev. 5:6)

The living creatures are those which travel with God's throne and they do His will.  The associated link of the conjunction "and" is not to the Lamb, but to the throne.  Therefore, "en meso" does not have to be repeated again before the living creatures as they are not separate from the throne.  They reflect the image of Christ.  The Lamb / Christ is not a part of them.

Excerpt from my post "The Signs of Revelation - Part IV: Symbols of the Throne Scene Rev. 4 & 5":

The KJV translates these as “beasts,” which is a meaning given in Strong’s, but which is not the context of these scriptures.  These are of a completely different office and nature than of the predator beasts of chapters 13 – 20.  These are the living creatures who are the agents of God, with the characteristics of God as described in Ez. chap. 1, and are correctly translated so in Young’s Literal Translation of the above verses.

Rev. 4:6-7, ”and before the throne [is] a sea of glass like to crystal, and in the midst of the throne, and round the throne, [are] four living creatures, full of eyes before and behind;  7 and the first living creature [is] like a lion, and the second living creature [is] like a calf, and the third living creature hath the face as a man, and the fourth living creature [is] like an eagle flying.” (YLT)

Compare with Ezekiel’s description:

Ez. 1:5, 10; “And out of its midst [is] a likeness of four living creatures, and this [is] their appearance; a likeness of man [is] to them,”    ….. “10 As to the likeness of their faces, the face of a man, and the face of a lion, toward the right [are] to them four, and the face of an ox on the left [are] to them four, and the face of an eagle [are] to them four.” (YLT)

These are the same which Ezekiel identifies as the cherubim of Ez. 1:15, 20:

”15 And the cherubs are lifted up, it [is] the living creature that I saw by the river Chebar.“…..20It [is] the living creature that I saw under the God of Israel by the river Chebar, and I know that they are cherubs.”  ...

Isa. 6:2 calls them “seraphim:”

*”Above it stood the seraphims: each one had six wings; with twain he covered his face, and with twain he covered his feet, and with twain he did fly.  3 And one cried unto another, and said, Holy, holy, holy, is the Lord of hosts: the whole earth is full of his glory.”*  (KJV)

These are burning ones symbolizing judgment of God.  God’s fury is fire (Ex. 3:2; Psa 21:9; Nah.1:6; Heb 12:29), and these have a burning flame described in Ez. 1:13 as coals of fire, and burning lamps going up and down their bodies.  Isaiah sees them with six wings, whereas Ezekiel sees four wings and four faces.  They fly where God wills them to go (Ez. 1:12, 20).  They hand out coals of fire, which are the judgments from God (Is. 6:6; Ez. 10:2, 7)

See Ez. 10:2, “And he spake unto the man clothed with linen, and said, Go in between the wheels, even under the cherub, and fill thine hand with coals of fire from between the cherubims, and scatter them over the city. And he went in in my sight.”  (KJV)

They are represented in the wilderness tabernacle over the mercy seat in the holy of holies (Ex. 25: 18-20), which is a representation of the throne of God.

Ex. 25:22, “And there I will meet with thee, and I will commune with thee from above the mercy seat, from between the two cherubims which are upon the ark of the testimony, of all things which I will give thee in commandment unto the children of Israel.” (KJV)

And we go back to Gen. 3:24, “ So he drove out the man; and he placed at the east of the garden of Eden Cherubims, and a flaming sword which turned every way, to keep the way of the tree of life.”

They are guardians, agents / angels of God, bearing his chariot in Ezekiel, and constantly doing the will of the Almighty."   Source [ShreddingTheVeil](https://shreddingtheveil.org/2017/03/09/signs-of-revelation-part-iv-symbols-of-the-throne-scene-chap-4-5/)

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

This in Revelation 5 is a symbolic picture of the Lord coming to give us an understanding by the opening up of the Scriptures through the Spirit of Truth which makes them “living”.  He is in the midst of all these things as He is the one opening up the Scriptures to our hearing ears and minds and hearts.  It is His interpretation of them….the living Scriptures… in the Spirit of God which is breathed into their words which correctly interprets them.

When we hear His voice as He opens up the Scriptures to our minds, the only way to enter into that understanding is to keep the sacrifice of our Lord (the Lamb) by dying to sin.

We are not to resist what we hear  (resisting the Spirit of Truth’s interpretation of the Scriptures) by speaking evil words and acting out of wrath but keep His sacrifice (the Lamb as it had been slain) in our lives so that we may enter in to know the mysteries.  We are then before the Throne of Judgment once we hear His voice interpreting the Scriptures to our ears.

> Revelation 5:6-8 KJV (6)  *And I beheld, and, lo, in the midst of the
>   throne and of the four beasts, and in the midst of the elders, **stood a
>   Lamb as it had been slain**, having seven horns and seven eyes, which
>   are the seven Spirits of God sent forth into all the earth. (7)  And
>   he came and took the book out of the right hand of him that sat upon
>   the throne.*

When one hears the heavenly interpretation of the Scriptures by the Lord in the Spirit of Truth, it produces joy within the heart (the harps) and thanksgiving and the praising of God…..the golden cups (vials) of odors.  Our mouths are those golden “cups” that praise Him above and the words we use are “prayers” to Him and are pleasing to Him…pleasant aromas going to Heaven where God sits on the Throne.

> (8)  *And when he had taken the book, the four beasts and four and
>   twenty elders fell down before the Lamb, **having every one of them
>   harps, and golden vials full of odours, which are the prayers of
>   saints**.*

We are not to be found “drunk” on the wine of wrath towards what we hear the Spirit saying….the correct interpretation of the Scriptures….but instead be filled with what the Spirit is saying to the churches.   We are to remember to always do the will of the Lord.  He that has ears to hear, let him hear what the Spirit is saying….being filled with that Spirit by drinking in all of the words we hear.

> Ephesians 5:17-21 KJV (17)  *Wherefore be ye not unwise, but
>   understanding what the will of the Lord is. (18)  **And be not drunk
>   with wine, wherein is excess; but be filled with the Spirit**;*

When we do the will of the Lord at the hearing of the living Scriptures, then we shall rejoice within our hearts (the “harps”) to the Lord and give thanks always for all things unto God (the golden cups full of odors….the mouths speaking thanksgiving and praise to God).

> (19)  ***Speaking to yourselves in psalms and hymns and spiritual songs,
>   singing and making melody in your heart to the Lord; (20)  Giving
>   thanks always for all things unto God and the Father in the name of
>   our Lord Jesus Christ***; (21)  Submitting yourselves one to another in
>   the fear of God.

The 4 “living creatures” are the Holy Scriptures that are God-breathed by the Spirit.  It is the Spirit of God that correctly interprets them and makes them “living”.  They are not the private interpretation of men that wrest the Scriptures in their own fleshly understanding of them but are interpreted by those who are moved by the Spirit.

Only by becoming a child as regarding evil can we know the Holy Scriptures…..the living Scriptures that are God-breathed (spoken in the Spirit of God) and not the Scriptures that man interprets with his own private interpretation (the word of man).   The Holy Scriptures day and night never stop saying: "'Holy, holy, holy is the Lord God Almighty”.

> 2 Timothy 3:15-17 KJV (15)  ***And that from a child thou hast known the
>   holy scriptures, which are able to make thee wise unto salvation
>   through faith which is in Christ Jesus.***

The Scriptures have 4 “faces”.  All Scripture as interpreted by the Spirit of God (God-breathed) is profitable for teaching (the ox) ….for reproof (lion?)….for correction (eagle?)…..and for instruction in righteousness that the man (Anthropos =“Man-faced”) of God may be perfect (fresh).

Greek for “for”  = “pros” which means “toward, facing, face”.  4 “faces” of the living Scriptures.

> (16)  ***All scripture is given by inspiration of God,*** and is profitable
>   **for** doctrine, **for** reproof, **for** correction, **for** instruction in
>   righteousness: (17)  **That the man of God** may be perfect, throughly
>   furnished unto all good works. It is the Lord in the midst of the 4
>   living creatures interpreting them (the book that is opened to our
>   understanding).

The Holy Scriptures  are able to make you wise unto salvation through faith which is in Christ Jesus and this is what causes our “face to shine” and the hardness of it shall be changed in the face of our Lord Jesus.   The man of God shall be fresh as it shows forth our good works in our outer mortal flesh which is the manifest life of Jesus.

The wise man shall know the interpretation of the Scriptures and his face shall shine. The "man"...the man-face...shall be "fresh" as the hardness of the face shall be changed.

> Ecclesiastes 8:1-5 KJV (1)  *Who is as the wise man? and who knoweth
>   the interpretation of a thing? a man's wisdom **maketh his face to
>   shine, and the boldness of his face shall be changed**.*

When we shall hear His interpretation of the Scriptures (which makes them living), we are to remember to let brotherly love continue always and entertain strangers and their words for they may be speaking His words from above.  Where the Word of the King is, there is power.

> (2)  ***I counsel thee to keep the king's commandmen***t, and that in regard
>   of the oath of God. (3)  Be not hasty to go out of his sight: stand
>   not in an evil thing; for he doeth whatsoever pleaseth him. (4)  Where
>   the word of a king is, there is power: and who may say unto him, What
>   doest thou?

Whosoever shall keep the commandment shall feel no evil thing (a fearful expectation of the judgment and fiery indignation) and a wise man’s heart discerns both time and judgment.

> (5)  **Whoso keepeth the commandment shall feel no evil thing: and a
>   wise man's heart discerneth both time and judgment.**

In the time that we hear His voice opening up the Scriptures to our understanding, it is the time of  judgment at the “great white throne”.

The books…the things which are written in the books...the Scriptures… are opened up to our ears and we are judged according to how we respond towards the hearing of His interpretation of them.  It will be according to our works that we are judged….and His judgment is just.

> Revelation 20:12 KJV (12)  *And I saw the dead, small and great, stand
>   before God; **and the books were opened: and another book was opened,
>   which is the book of life: and the dead were judged out of those
>   things which were written in the books, according to their works.***

We are to hear His interpretation of the Scriptures and believe on Him that sent the Son to give us an understanding so that we may know Him who is true.  We show we know God by remembering to do His will at the hearing of the Son's interpretation that will challenge all that we thought we understood.  We are then found written in the book of life as we shall pass from death unto life.

> John 5:24-29 KJV (24)  *Verily, verily, I say unto you, He that heareth
>   my word, and believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and
>   shall not come into condemnation; but is passed from death unto life.*

The “dead”…the dead in trespasses and sins….shall hear His the voice of the Son of God as He shall interpret the Scriptures in this coming time in the Spirit of Truth.  They that will truly hear (believe in what they hear) shall live...being found written in the book of life.   They will hear and rejoice at what He has to say.

> (25)  *Verily, verily, I say unto you, The hour is coming, and now is,
>   w**hen the dead shall hear the voice of the Son of God: and they that
>   hear shall live.** (26)  For as the Father hath life in himself; so hath
>   he given to the Son to have life in himself; (27)  And hath given him
>   authority to execute judgment also, because he is the Son of man*.

Those who are in the “graves”….the churches of carnally-thinking men where there are envy and strife and hatred of one another (being “dead” in trespasses and sins)….shall hear His voice.

Some will come forth and do good towards the hearing of His voice unto the standing up of life and others will do evil in response to the hearing of His interpretation of the Scriptures.  They will do evil unto the standing up of the judgment.  As He hears our response, He judges and His judgment is just (the great white throne).

> (28)  *Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which all
>   that are in the graves shall hear his voice, (29)  **And shall come
>   forth; they that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and
>   they that have done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation**.*

If we continue to sin willfully ( continuing to speak evil even when we have been instructed to remember to let brotherly love continue) AFTER receiving the knowledge (the full knowledge) of the Truth, then there remains no more sacrifice for sins but shall feel an evil thing:  a certain fearful looking for judgment and fiery indignation.

> Hebrews 10: KJV (26)  **For if we sin wilfully after that we have
>   received the knowledge of the truth, there remaineth no more sacrifice
>   for sins, (27)  But a certain fearful looking for of judgment and
>   fiery indignation, which shall devour the adversaries.**  (28)  He that
>   despised Moses' law died without mercy under two or three witnesses:
>   (29)  Of how much sorer punishment, suppose ye, shall he be thought
>   worthy, who hath trodden under foot the Son of God, and hath counted
>   the blood of the covenant, wherewith he was sanctified, an unholy
>   thing, and hath done despite unto the Spirit of grace? (30)  For we
>   know him that hath said, Vengeance belongeth unto me, I will
>   recompense, saith the Lord. And again, The Lord shall judge his
>   people. (31)  It is a fearful thing to fall into the hands of the
>   living God.

The tongue is a fire that sets one on the fire of the Judgment as one will speak evil at the hearing of His voice that interprets the Scriptures in this coming time.  There will then be no more sacrifice for willful sins…willfully speaking evil… and disregarding the holy covenant to have brotherly love.  They will not then be found written in the book of life and will be cast into the lake of fire as a final judgment upon them where there will be no mercy shown to them.

The tongue will bring torment to those who will be judged…and there will be no mercy then for they will have rejected His words and did those things that did not please Him.

Their own evil speaking will not cease (the worm…the blurting of evil… will not die) nor will the torment that will come from it (the fire will not be quenched)….until they perish from this earth.

The judgment is final until they die as “death and hell” were also cast into the lake of fire.   This means it is a final judgment upon them until they die and they will not understand  (Hades = the unknown) as the wicked shall not understand.

They will not enter into His understanding as they will have rejected His knowledge in order to keep their own.  They will not have lost their lives to save it but will seek to keep their life only to lose it.

> Revelation 20:14-15 KJV (14)  ***And death and hell were cast into the
>   lake of fire. This is the second death. (15)  And whosoever was not
>   found written in the book of life was cast into the lake of fire***.

Paul lost his own religious thoughts and ways in order to gain the excellency of the knowledge of Christ Jesus our Lord.   He counted all of his own religious things as a “loss” and did not seek to keep his own righteousness at the hearing of the Lord and His knowledge.  Paul did not go about defending his own religious thoughts and ways but counted it all as a loss in order to gain His knowledge.

> Philippians 3:6-11 KJV (6)  *Concerning zeal, persecuting the church;
>   touching the righteousness which is in the law, blameless. (7)  **But
>   what things were gain to me, those I counted loss for Christ.** (8)  Yea
>   doubtless, and **I count all things but loss for the excellency of the
>   knowledge of Christ Jesus my Lord:** for whom I have suffered the loss
>   of all things, and do count them but dung, that I may win Christ,*

He suffered the loss of his own religiousness in order to be found in Him at the hearing of His voice.  He did not go about defending his own righteousness but lost his life so that he may know Him.  Paul believed the Lord and did not go about defending his own thoughts and ways.

> (9)  ***And be found in him, not having mine own righteousness,*** which is
>   of the law, but that which is through the faith of Christ, **the
>   righteousness which is of God by faith: (10)  That I may know him,** and
>   the power of his resurrection, and the fellowship of his sufferings,
>   being made conformable unto his death; (11)  If by any means I might
>   attain unto the resurrection of the dead.